# ¿Como hacer la siguiente relación en Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, relaciones

Tabla `Jobs` con campos `(id, name`).

Tabla `JobsCandidates` con campos `(job_id, user_id)`

Tabla `Users` con campos `(id, name, avatar)`

Las relaciones se encuentran en la tabla `JobsCandidates` de la siguiente manera:

```
+-----------------------+
  user_id   |  job_id
+-----------------------+
      1           1
      2           1
+-----------------------+
```

Como podria realizar la siguiente relación en laravel de la manera más compacta posible, actualmente la tengo de la siguiente manera.

Modelo `Job`

```
class Job extends Model
{
    public function candidates(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\JobCandidate')->with('candidate');
    }
}
```

Modelo `JobCandidate`

```
class JobCandidate extends Model
{
    public function candidate(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

> Controller

```
$jobs = Job::with('candidates')->get();
```

> Output

```
    datos job ....
    "candidates": [
        {
            "user_id": 1,
            "job_id": 1,
            "candidate": {
                "name": "Luis Javier ",
                "avatar": "avatar.png"
            }
        },
        {
            "user_id": 3,
            "job_id": 1,
            "candidate": {
                "name": "Abel",
                "avatar": "avatar.png"
            }
        }
    ],
```

si no me equivoco la manera más correcta es la siguiente:

```
"candidates": [
            {
             "name": "Luis Javier ",
             "avatar": "avatar.png"
            }...
```

Ocultando los valores ID.

**¿Como puedo lograr eso?**

Comment: No queda claro lo que deseas obtener, considera explicar de mejor manera a que te refieres con *mas compactas* así como explicar el resultado que deseas obtener

Comment: Tal y como dicen en el comentario anterior... no se entiende nada.

Answer (score 2):

Mm yo si entiendo a lo que te refieres. El tipo de relación que buscas es de muchos a muchos, y para realizarla se haría de la siguiente forma:

En tu modelo `Job`:

```
public function candidates(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'jobs_users' /* En este parámetro reemplazas por el nombre de tu tabla intermedia */, 'job_id', 'user_id');
}
```

En tu modelo `User`:

```
public function jobs(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Jobs', 'jobs_users' /* En este parámetro reemplazas por el nombre de tu tabla intermedia */, 'user_id', 'job_id');
}
```

De esta manera cuando realices:

```
$jobs = Job::with('candidates')->get();
```

Podrás acceder a los candidatos que estén conectados a tus registros de la tabla "jobs" mediante tu tabla intermedia.

```
$jobs[0]->candidates; //Esto te devolverá una colección de candidatos.
```

El modelo que le pertenece a tu tabla intermedia, en este caso `JobsCandidates` no te sería ya de mucha utilidad, a menos que vayas a trabajar otras operaciones con datos ajenos a "users" y "jobs".

Comment: Ojalá pudieran poner el motivo del voto negativo y no nada más emitir el voto al aire y porque sí, el OP dio los datos de los modelos y quiere saber la relación que se debe de hacer basándose en esos datos proporcionados, ¿cuál es el problema?